# Unable to open VS Code on Ubuntu VM instance on Google Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vnc, google-cloud, visual-studio-code

I am facing a problem when trying to open VS Code on my Virtual machine in Google cloud using VNC viewer. 
It's Real VNC,
and I checked that vscode is not running in multiple VNC sessions.

The VM is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I was able to install the application [VS Code] and see it listed with the other applications, but I am not able to open it, either by clicking on the icon or running it via the terminal.

When I tried to run VS code through the terminal, it didn't give any errors!

I tried to follow [a related issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72214),
but I was not able to solve my problem.

For installation, I installed the deb package from the VS code website and did `sudo dpkg –i <package_name>` to install it.

After following Robot Johnny's answer below,
this is the response for `code --verbose`:

```
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[13988:1206/040556.509538:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(425)] glxQueryVersion failed
[13988:1206/040556.509600:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(147)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[13988:1206/040556.510808:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(170)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[13966:1206/040556.517587:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1193)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[13966:1206/040556.554491:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(967)] Reinitialized the GPU process after a crash. The reported initialization time was 14 ms
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.578Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.579Z] from: /usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.579Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  version: false,
  help: false,
  telemetry: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  'extension-development-confirm-save': false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-getting-started': false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'sticky-quickopen': false,
  'disable-restore-windows': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'disable-user-env-probe': false,
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  'driver-verbose': false,
  force: false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  nolazy: false
}
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.580Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.581Z] Resolved machine identifier: 8195d34eeeec20241a1db1a84b63b5309fc06715a4960b3481584f41d87c0955 (trueMachineId: undefined)
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.597Z] update#setState idle
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.600Z] [storage state.vscdb] 
open(/home/developer/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb, retryOnBusy: true)
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.600Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2019-12-06T04:05:56.601Z] windowsManager#open
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
[13966:1206/040556.659702:ERROR:atom_browser_main_parts.cc(183)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the U&L community. In order for us to be able to help, we will need further information. Please can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/555520/edit) your question and paste exactly what you did to install `vs code`, along with any output. If it's a fresh VM with nothing on it, it may be worth just starting from scratch rather than trying to uninstall and re-install so we get the most accurate output. FYI some VNC clients don't allow you to copy text. If that's the case for you, I'd recommend trying [realvnc](https://www.realvnc.com/en/)

Comment: Try running `code --verbose` from a terminal. It might be useful to include that output in your question.

Comment: Check if you have vscode running in multiple X (or VNC) sessions. Unfortunately it doesn't support that. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57843

Comment: The RANDR error sounds interesting. Is `DISPLAY=:1` correct? What's your VNC server app called? There are several versions these days (RealVNC, UltraVNC, TigerVNC, etc.) that should support RANDR.

Comment: It's Real VNC and I also checked that vscode is not running in multiple VNC sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either something is wrong with the deb package or something else has not installed correctly along the way.

I would recommend starting with a new VM deployment to ensure you have a clean VM.

Then, As per [this tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-18-04/):

> First, update the packages index and install the dependencies by
>   typing:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
> ```
>
> Next, import the Microsoft GPG key using the following wget command:
>
> ```
> wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> And enable the Visual Studio Code repository by typing:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
> ```
>
> Once the apt repository is enabled, install the latest version of
>   Visual Studio Code with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install code
> ```

That’s it. Visual Studio Code has been installed on your Ubuntu
 machine and you can start using it; either via terminal by typing
 `code` or via the UI.